# Distinguishing between Pydantic Models with same fields

Tags: python, pydantic, abc

I'm using Pydantic to define hierarchical data in which there are models with identical attributes.

However, when I save and load these models, Pydantic can no longer distinguish which model was used and picks the first one in the field type annotation.

I understand that this is expected behavior based on the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions).
However, the class type information is important to my application.

What is the recommended way to distinguish between different classes in Pydantic?  One hack is to simply add an extraneous field to one of the models, but I'd like to find a more elegant solution.

See the simplified example below: `container` is initialized with data of type `DataB`, but after exporting and loading, the new `container` has data of type `DataA` as it's the first element in the type declaration of `container.data`.

Thanks for your help!

```py
from abc import ABC
from pydantic import BaseModel #pydantic 1.8.2
from typing import Union

class Data(BaseModel, ABC):
    """ base class for a Member """
    number: float

class DataA(Data):
    """ A type of Data"""
    pass

class DataB(Data):
    """ Another type of Data """
    pass

class Container(BaseModel):
    """ container holds a subclass of Data """
    data: Union[DataA, DataB]

# initialize container with DataB
data = DataB(number=1.0)
container = Container(data=data)

# export container to string and load new container from string
string = container.json()
new_container = Container.parse_raw(string)

# look at type of container.data
print(type(new_container.data).__name__)
# >>> DataA
```

Comment: `string` here is just the the json `{"data": {"number": 1.0}}`. You toss out any data about the type when you make the conversion to json. There's no way for python to understand  your intent unless you add some data to make this clear. If they are truly indistinguishable, then it begs the question why have both? If they're *not* indistinguishable, then you have a means to distinguish (by definition) and you can use that to indicate the type.

Comment: exactly.  I guess my question is what is a reasonable workaround.  What I have come up with is very hacky (adding some extra field to `DataB` that does nothing, for example).  Would like a way to do this systematically for a very complicated model.

Comment: interestingly enough, I remember this question been brought up before. I honestly didn't feel like this use case was important or even used at all, but it turns out more than one person was interested in this kind of support before.

Comment: also imho (I might be missing something) but the simplest way to handle this would be to add a field `__class__` with the qualified class name when serializing the object, then when deserializing for union types, check this field to load it to the correct type based on the union types. I honestly can't think of a more elegant solution that wouldn't turn out to be more complicated tbh.

Comment: Hi @rv.kvetch same person :), but slightly more general question.  I think I found a decent workaround, I will post my answer but appreciate the help and discussion.

Comment: ah, understand. I did realize that too earlier but then forgot to take down my comment lol. all good :-)

Comment: @twhughes I know you're probably set with the approach using `pydantic`, but I added an alternate option below that I've been able to test with. Just adding it here for posterity, and also because I hadn't gotten around to add support (in general) for dataclasses within annotated `Union` types before now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As correctly noted in the comments, without storing additional information models cannot be distinguished when parsing.

As of today (pydantic v1.8.2), the most canonical way to distinguish models when parsing in a `Union` (in case of ambiguity) is to explicitly add a type specifier [`Literal`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#literal-type). It will look like this:

```
from abc import ABC
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union, Literal

class Data(BaseModel, ABC):
    """ base class for a Member """
    number: float


class DataA(Data):
    """ A type of Data"""
    tag: Literal['A'] = 'A'


class DataB(Data):
    """ Another type of Data """
    tag: Literal['B'] = 'B'


class Container(BaseModel):
    """ container holds a subclass of Data """
    data: Union[DataA, DataB]


# initialize container with DataB
data = DataB(number=1.0)
container = Container(data=data)

# export container to string and load new container from string
string = container.json()
new_container = Container.parse_raw(string)


# look at type of container.data
print(type(new_container.data).__name__)
# >>> DataB
```

This method can be automated, but you can use it at your own responsibility, since it breaks static typing and uses objects that may change in future versions:

```
from pydantic.fields import ModelField

class Data(BaseModel, ABC):
    """ base class for a Member """
    number: float

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        name = 'tag'
        value = cls.__name__
        annotation = Literal[value]

        tag_field = ModelField.infer(name=name, value=value, annotation=annotation, class_validators=None, config=cls.__config__)
        cls.__fields__[name] = tag_field
        cls.__annotations__[name] = annotation


class DataA(Data):
    """ A type of Data"""
    pass


class DataB(Data):
    """ Another type of Data """
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I hadn't thought of using `Literal` but this does seem like a pretty good solution.  See mine below, which is a bit more complex.  Do you see any potential pitfalls?  It seems to work both on the simple test case and when implemented in my more complicated project model

Comment: Actually I realized the class method version that I pasted below does not really work, but when I embedded similar code in the Data class it did.  Might need some tweaking.

Comment: The first solution in this answer is the most robust in my  eyes. It has the benefit that, if you later rename `DataA` to another name, or move the class to another module, it still won't break anything.

Comment: I'm curious, how would you modify your 2nd solution such that it propagates to further subclasses of DataA and DataB?  When I try this I get errors such as ```AttributeError: type object '{class name}' has no attribute '__annotations__'```

Comment: If you add `class DataBB(DataB):  pass` in the second solution union everything should work

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to take the opportunity to list another possible alternative here to `pydantic` - which already supports this use case very well, as per below answer.

I am the creator and maintainer of a relatively newer and lesser-known JSON serialization library, the Dataclass Wizard - which relies on the Python `dataclasses` module to perform its magic. As of the latest version, 0.14.0, the `dataclass-wizard` now supports dataclasses within Union types. Previously, it did not support dataclasses within `Union` types at all, which was kind of a glaring omission, and something on my "to-do" list of things to (eventually) add support for.

As of the latest, it should now support defining dataclasses within `Union` types. The reason it did not *generally* work before, is because the data being de-serialized is often a JSON object, which only knows simple types such as arrays and  dictionaries, for example. A `dict` type would not otherwise match any of the `Union[Data1, Data2]` types, even if the object had all the correct dataclass fields as keys. This is simply because it doesn't compare the `dict` object against each of the dataclass fields in the `Union` types, though that might change in a future release.

So in any case, here is a simple example to demonstrate the usage of dataclasses in `Union` types, using a class inheritance model with the `JSONWizard` mixin class:

###### With Class Inheritance

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class Data(ABC):
    """ base class for a Member """
    number: float


class DataA(Data, JSONWizard):
    """ A type of Data"""

    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        """
        This defines a custom tag that uniquely identifies the dataclass.
        """
        tag = 'A'


class DataB(Data, JSONWizard):
    """ Another type of Data """

    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        """
        This defines a custom tag that uniquely identifies the dataclass.
        """
        tag = 'B'


@dataclass
class Container(JSONWizard):
    """ container holds a subclass of Data """
    data: Union[DataA, DataB]
```

The usage is shown below, and is again pretty straightforward. It relies on a special `__tag__` key set in a dictionary or JSON object to marshal it into the correct dataclass, based on the `Meta.tag` value for that class, that we have set up above.

```py
print('== Load with DataA ==')

input_dict = {
    'data': {
        'number': '1.0',
        '__tag__': 'A'
    }
}

# De-serialize the `dict` object to a `Container` instance.
container = Container.from_dict(input_dict)

print(repr(container))
# prints:
#   Container(data=DataA(number=1.0))

# Show the prettified JSON representation of the instance.
print(container)

# Assert we load the correct dataclass from the annotated `Union` types
assert type(container.data) == DataA

print()

print('== Load with DataB ==')

# initialize container with DataB
data_b = DataB(number=2.0)
container = Container(data=data_b)

print(repr(container))
# prints:
#   Container(data=DataB(number=2.0))

# Show the prettified JSON representation of the instance.
print(container)

# Assert we load the correct dataclass from the annotated `Union` types
assert type(container.data) == DataB

# Assert we end up with the same instance when serializing and de-serializing
# our data.
string = container.to_json()
assert container == Container.from_json(string)
```

###### Without Class Inheritance

Here is the same example as above, but with relying solely on `dataclasses`, without using any special class inheritance model:

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union

from dataclass_wizard import asdict, fromdict, LoadMeta


@dataclass
class Data(ABC):
    """ base class for a Member """
    number: float


class DataA(Data):
    """ A type of Data"""


class DataB(Data):
    """ Another type of Data """


@dataclass
class Container:
    """ container holds a subclass of Data """
    data: Union[DataA, DataB]


# Setup tags for the dataclasses. This can be passed into either
# `LoadMeta` or `DumpMeta`.
#
# Note that I'm not a fan of this syntax either, so it might change. I was
# thinking of something more explicit, like `LoadMeta(...).bind_to(class)`
LoadMeta(DataA, tag='A')
LoadMeta(DataB, tag='B')

# The rest is the same as before.

# initialize container with DataB
data = DataB(number=2.0)
container = Container(data=data)

print(repr(container))
# prints:
#   Container(data=DataB(number=2.0))

# Assert we load the correct dataclass from the annotated `Union` types
assert type(container.data) == DataB

# Assert we end up with the same data when serializing and de-serializing.
out_dict = asdict(container)
assert container == fromdict(Container, out_dict)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, I came to the point that I need to serialize to JSON bunch of stdlib dataclass instances, some of them are wrapped into dicts, some into other dataclasses, tried to convert my code into pydantic , tried another library, tried to write custom serializer - had several issues with them, and only with your library I was able to serialize into JSON in like 5 minutes after pip install.

Comment: Awesome, glad to know that it helped. Also just adding this for awareness, but pydantic does support drop-in [dataclasses](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/) in case one doesn't want to work with their models for whatever reason. They are both great libraries in general, but again glad to know it worked out for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to hack something together in the meantime using custom validators.
Basically the class decorator adds a `class_name: str` field, which is added to the json string.  The validator then looks up the correct subclass based on its value.

```py
def register_distinct_subclasses(fields: tuple):
    """ fields is tuple of subclasses that we want to be registered as distinct """

    field_map = {field.__name__: field for field in fields}

    def _register_distinct_subclasses(cls):
        """ cls is the superclass of fields, which we add a new validator to """

        orig_init = cls.__init__

        class _class:
            class_name: str

            def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                class_name = type(self).__name__
                kwargs["class_name"] = class_name
                orig_init(**kwargs)

            @classmethod
            def __get_validators__(cls):
                yield cls.validate

            @classmethod
            def validate(cls, v):
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    class_name = v.get("class_name")
                    json_string = json.dumps(v)
                else:
                    class_name = v.class_name
                    json_string = v.json()
                cls_type = field_map[class_name]
                return cls_type.parse_raw(json_string)

        return _class
    return _register_distinct_subclasses
```

which is called as follows

```py
Data = register_distinct_subclasses((DataA, DataB))(Data)
```